# Make vim run scripts with parameters from source code

Tags: python, vim

I use vim as an editor for writing shell (bash) and Python programs. Often, I need to pass different parameters to the program I develop to test/debug in different combination. For C sources a Makefile is responsible for building and running stuff, so it can be edited in the next tab, passing new parameters to the program every time I press F9, which executes 'make run'. There is no such thing as Makefile for scripts, so I have to run them manually in the next tab in Konsole, changing parameters, which seems to be pretty inefficient.

For Python, as an example, I have the following settings in .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType python call Python_source()
func! Python_source()
    setlocal number cursorline
    setlocal shiftwidth=2
    setlocal foldmethod=indent

    map <F9> :w \| :!python %<CR>
    imap <F9> <Esc> :w \| :!python %<CR>
    ...
endfunc
```

Is there any way to store parameters in script source code (in comment, for example) and then pass it to the script as a parameter like this:

```
#vimparameter='-f -a --bus 1'
```

in .vimrc:

```
map <F9> :w \| :!python % $vimparameter<CR>
imap <F9> <Esc> :w \| :!python % $vimparameter<CR>
```

Or any other reasonable way to easy change and then pass parameters to the script, executed by F9 shortcut?

As suggested my @Matt, `modelines` could be used to pass some predefined line as an arguments to the command:

```
autocmd FileType python call Python_source()
...
func! LWargs()
    set lw=''
    doautocmd BufRead
    if len(&lw) > 0 && len(&lw) < 512
        return ' ' . &lw
    endif
    return ''
endfunc

func! Python_source()
...
    map <F9> :w \| :exe '!python' '%:p' . LWargs()<CR>
    imap <F9> <Esc> :w \| :exe '!python' '%:p' . LWargs()<CR>
...
endfunc
```

And then in source code parameters can be predefined with:

```
# vim: lw=--bus\ 10\ -f
```

'modeline' should be set.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from writing a Makefile and using it in a non-C project. Build tools are commonly used in scripting languages (think Ruby's `Rakefile`) and if it suits your project, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "modeline" to set some normally unused option. 'lispwords' seems just fine (unless you're a LISP programmer): it's a buffer-local string which is only used for lisp indenting. So you can do in python:

```
# vim: lw=-f\ -a\ --bus\ 1

import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

And in vimscript something like:

```
update
"ensure modeline is re-read
doautocmd BufRead
let l:args = (len(&lw) < 500) ? &lw : ''
exe '!python' shellescape(expand('%:p')) l:args
```

Comment: It seems that Vim reads modeline once when file is opened, therefore it will ignore all changes made in buffer, even if it saved.

Comment: I'm not a vim script programmer at all, but with your help was able to write some simple solution that does what I need. Originally, I was going to write a function, that will parse buffer for some special string and get arguments past it, but modeline work just fine for me. Thanks!